# calculate leave year from anniversary start date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, express, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to calculate someone holiday year start and end dates based on the anniversary of their joining date.

**For example** if someones joining date is 23/10/09 i need two fields calculated from this date which would be 23/10/13 for the start of their holiday year and the end of their leave year would be 22/10/14.

**Basically** i need a query that looks at the dd/mm of the joining date and the current date and calculates the two dates i require.

Another example would be joining date 01/02/10 and the start date of the leave year would be 01/02/14 and the end date date would be 31/01/15. The *field name* in my SQL database is

`[emp_join_date]`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

DATEADD() would be the function you need I believe:

```
declare @emp_join_date datetime = '2009-10-23'

select @emp_join_date as emp_join_date,
       DATEADD(YEAR,4,@emp_join_date) as holiday_start_date,
       DATEADD(YEAR,5,@emp_join_date)-1 as emp_end_date
```